# Convert hh:mm to ISO 8601 with current date in Javascript / Momen.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, iso8601, reactstrap

I have a variable `filterStartHour` which depends on a user input (`Reactstrap` Input of type `time`)
I'm trying to convert the input which is in the `hh:mm` format (e.g *14:32*) to *ISO 8601* with the current date (e.g *2020-06-29T14:32:00.000Z*).

This is what I have tried.

```js
this.setState({ filterStartHour: moment(this.state.filterStartHour).format() }) // Or with .toISOString()
```

But they return either `Invalid date` or `null` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you just tell moment the format of the input:

```js
const time = '15:42';
const isoDate = moment.utc(time, "HH:mm");

console.log(isoDate.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate date using moment and then add your time to the date.

```js
const time = '15:42',
      date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
      isoDate = `${date}T${time}:00.000Z`;

console.log(isoDate)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Smells like a code hack but it gets the job done so thank you very much! You saved me hours of trying!